# StarUML for Python

Tags: python, staruml

Is there a way using StarUML for reverse engineering Python code to a class diagramm?
In the StarUML docs, they say there are modules for language support, but I couldn't find any further information about where and how to install and use.

Other UML tools I found didn't match my idea of how a diagramm should look like.
I know it is a bit problematic generating class diagramms for python, because it's compiled to runtime and will probably change then. 
But I'm using Python to build my bachelor thesis and my Prof. loves UML. He really takes care of doing this correctly.

Can anybody help me pls?

Comment: You then should change you title and question to ask how to create uml diagrams from python code. StarUML is too distracting. Also you should not provide an answer(staruml) but a problem (uml class diagram from python code). That will help people answer. It is good that you stated what you did.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple possibility: Use PyCharm, a python IDE, which has an integrated UML generator (only in the pro version which is free for students).